# Bash script to run FFmpeg concat on MP4 files in batches of 5

Tags: command-line, bash, ffmpeg

I like to create a Bash script to concatenate MP4 files using FFmpeg, in batches of 5 files at a time for a directory with 100 MP4 files, so that afterwards there would be 20 files like:

001_005.mp4, 006_010.mp4, and so on...

instead of just 1 file consisting of all 100 files.

Contents of mylist.txt:

```
file 001.mp4
file 002.mp4
file 003.mp4
file 004.mp4
file 005.mp4
............
file 099.mp4
file 100.mp4
```

Though I've found a command that works just fine ([from this StackOverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7333232/how-to-concatenate-two-mp4-files-using-ffmpeg)), it would create only 1 file consisting all 100 files.

```
#!/bin/bash

cd /home/admn/Downloads/MP4_Files;

# Create mylist.txt:
for f in *.mp4
do
    echo "file $f" >> mylist.txt
done;

# Concatenate files:
ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i mylist.txt -c copy output.mp4;
```

So, how do I modify the ffmpeg command so that it concat in batches of 5 files at a time.

All the files have exact same resolution (1080p), audio, and video codecs.

OS: Ubuntu MATE 21.04

ffmpeg version: 4.3.2-0+deb11u1ubuntu1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the following script will work.

- First try it as it is and check that it seems to do what you want
- Then remove `echo` from the line with `ffmpeg` to make it do its thing.

Check that the content of the temporary files `xaa' ...` xat` matches the names (and content) of the output files.

```
#!/bin/bash

> mylist.txt
for f in *.mp4
do
 echo "file '$f'" >> mylist.txt
done

< mylist.txt sort -t \' -n -k2 | split -l 5

k=1
for j in x*
do
 inc=$(wc -l "$j" | cut -d ' ' -f 1)
 m=$(printf "%03d" $((k)))
 n=$(printf "%03d" $((k+inc-1)))
 name="${m}_${n}.mp4"
 echo ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i "$j" -c copy "$name"
 k=$((k+5))
done
```

Comment: Perfect. Thank you so much :)

Comment: You are welcome @Jags :-)

Comment: Make sure to quote the files within `mylist.txt` or it will fail if there are spaces: `file 'input 001.mp4'`.

Comment: @llogan @sudodus Yes, thank you. When I changed the file name of 1st file to `001 abc.mp4`, the script did not create `001 abc_005.mp4` file. Though it did create `006_010.mp4` just fine. This is the error I got: `[concat @ 0x55a1060b7400] Impossible to open '001' | xaa: No such file or directory`.

Comment: @llogan, Thanks for this heads up. ,@Jags, I modified the **echo line** to manage file names with spaces. And this made it necessary to modify the **sort line** too (to specify the field separator).

Comment: @Jags, There seems to be a problem with quoting, The **ffmpeg line** cannot manage it correctly, but if I understand correctly, it worked with file names without a space. Am I right that your file names do not contain any spaces `001.mp4` ... `100.mp4` ? Or are the file names `file 001.mp4` ... `file 100.mp4`. This makes an important difference in treating the content of `mylist.txt`.

Comment: @Jags, It is a good idea to make the script 'future proof'. So let us fine tune it. I changed to single quotes around $f in the echo line - please test how it works.

Comment: @sudodus That did it, it's working just fine with one little exception, output filename. Script creates: `001_005.mp4` instead of `001 abc_005 xyz.mp4` It picks the part before the spaces of 1st and 5th file names. But this is kinda non-issue, and I don't wanna take any more of your time on this. So we can leave this as it is. Again, thank you so much :)

Comment: Again, you are welcome @Jags. It was nice to cooperate with you :-)

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is to use nested loops.

As long as there are files remaining, the inner loop uses `${@:1:5}` to take the next slice of (up to) 5 files.

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /home/admn/Downloads/MP4_Files;

shopt -s failglob
set -- *.mp4
while [[ $# -gt 0 ]]; do
    from=$(basename "$1" .mp4)
    for f in "${@:1:5}"; do
        #not essential in your case, but use @Q to quote/escape special characters
        echo "file ${f@Q}" >> mylist.txt
        shift
    done
    to=$(basename "$f" .mp4)
    ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i mylist.txt -c copy "${from}_${to}.mp4"
    rm mylist.txt
done
```

Comment: It's working great. Thank you so much :)

Comment: The `'*.mp4'` means that no files were found by the `set` at the beginning for some reason.  By default a failed glob results in the glob itself, not nothing. The added `shopt -s failglob` (or `nullglob`) prevents the failed glob from being treated as a single matched filename.

Comment: It's working with space in file name. Thanks alot.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `mylist.txt` exists in your current working directory, you can do something like this,

```sh
LINES=$(cat mylist.txt | wc -l)
BATCH_SIZE=5
BATCHES=$(($LINES/$BATCH_SIZE))             

for ((i=0;i<$BATCHES;i++))
do
  cat mylist.txt | head -n $((($i+1)*$BATCH_SIZE)) | tail -n $BATCH_SIZE > slist.txt
  ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i slist.txt -c copy $(($i*$BATCH_SIZE+1))_$((($i+1)*$BATCH_SIZE)).mp4
done
rm slist.txt
```

Comment: Thanks alot. Though I think, there are 2 issues. (1) You need `done` at the end (2) I'm getting errors: `[concat @ 0x55dbc36e3400] Impossible to open '/tmp/001.mp4'; /tmp/slist.txt: No such file or directory` and `[concat @ 0x56535fdc2400] Impossible to open '/tmp/006.mp4'; /tmp/slist.txt: No such file or directory`

Comment: Thank you for pointing out. Since I decided to create `slist.txt` in the `/tmp` directory, when I used `slist.txt` as input to ffmpeg all the file names inside `slist.txt` were considered relative to the `/tmp` directory which was the reason of the error. I have fixed this and tested it as well, it works now.

Comment: yes, it's working now. Though I just wanted to let you know, when I ran the script with 13 files, it created only 2 files: `1_5.mp4 and 6_10.mp4`, but with 15 files, it did create 3rd file `11_15.mp4` Thanks alot.